# Need help with binary plists

Tags: c#, java, binary, plist

I am writing a c# class that parses and writes binary plist files. All of the information I have gotten is from this Java implementation. http://www.koders.com/java/fidE214DE8B5C627C9E1C03ED93B488941BAE17AF01.aspx?s=base64#L111

I have successfully written the header and object table now I just need help understanding what the offset table and trailer is.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailer contains information about the location of the top level object as well as the number of objects contained into the offset table.

The offset table is used to store the position of the different objects. Each object can then be referenced one or more times within the plist.

For an up-to-date code of the original parser, [see this file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFBinaryPList.c).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I finished my c# implementation awhile back by doing a bit of trial and error with a binary plist reader. I put the source code on github so if you want to see it or use it you can go [here](https://github.com/animetrics/C-Sharp-Binary-Plist-Parser).

Comment: I will definitively take a look at it. Thanks for sharing.